# Use image from $randomImage variable in API request

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I want to get an image from `http://lorempixel.com` using the `$randomImage` variable in Postman and use this in another multipart request which accepts a `image/png` content-type. How can I do that? I think I need to store the image in a variable but I don't know how to do that. I am open to using collections or using pre-request script.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of `$randomImage` into an environment variable: `pm.environment.set("myImage", $randomImage));`

And then later access it via `pm.environment.get("myImage");`